# TortoiseGit hook scripts can not prevent start-commit

Tags: git, batch-file, hook, tortoisegit

I using msysgit and TortoiseGit 1.8.15.0 under Windows 7, and then set my start-commit-hook scripts file to './workflow.bat'. the script file content as follows:

> echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1>&2
>    echo Your commit has been blocked because it didn't include a log message. 1>&2
>    echo Do the commit again, this time with a log message that describes your changes. 1>&2
>    echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1>&2
>    exit 1

TortoiseGit will show alert box as expected when I commit my code, and then I click 'OK' button, it still show a tortoiseGit commit dialog to me after hook scripts finish. how to prevent the tortoiseGit commit dialog displays when the hook scripts exit with code 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pre-commit` hook can block the commit from actualizing by returning non-zero exit code.

`Start-commit` hook doesn't even have the log message to analyze because it will be entered by the user later in a subsequent commit dialog. The hook can, however, provide some preset commit message on its own.

Evidently there's no way for `Start-commit` hook to block the subsequent dialog. You can ask for this feature to be implemented on [their issue tracker](https://tortoisegit.org/issues) though.

Comment: Just FYI, TortoiseGit Issue [#2710](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2710) was filed and merge request [!50](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/merge_requests/50) has already been submitted to fix this issue.